# Apply Linear Regression to each row in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply a linear regression to each row in a dataframe.
After, I want to get each value (slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr, intercept_stderr) and add it to each corresponding row in the dataframe.

My dataframe has cities (rows) and values (columns) for each day. Different cities can have data for a different number of days

Like this (example):

| City | Day1 | Day2 | Day3 | Day4 | Day5 | Day6 | Day7 | Day8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abatia |  | 0.3299 | 0.3105 | 0.3105 | 0.31055 | 0.2717 | 0.1552 | 0.1358 |
| Adrian |  |  |  | 0.1725 | 0.1725 | 0.2957 | 0.2710 | 0.3450 |
| Agudos | 0.0298 | 0.0298 | 0.0298 | 0.0298 | 0.0298 | 0.0447 | 0.0149 | 0.0149 |

I´m trying to use the iterrows. Somethink like this:

```
for indice, linha in df.iterrows():
    x = list(range(1,linha.count()+1))
    y = df.loc[[indice]]
    lr = list(linregress(x, y))
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "doesn't work". Please see [ask]. Since you're new, please also take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic)
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and how to provide a [mre]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.  Set the city as the index so that you can apply the regression to the remaining values per row.

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
{'City': {0: 'Abatia', 1: 'Adrian', 2: 'Agudos'},
 'Day1': {0: 0.329968944, 1: 0.172503019, 2: 0.029864564},
 'Day2': {0: 0.310559006, 1: 0.172503019, 2: 0.029864564},
 'Day3': {0: 0.310559006, 1: 0.295719461, 2: 0.029864564},
 'Day4': {0: 0.310559006, 1: 0.271076172, 2: 0.029864564},
 'Day5': {0: 0.27173913, 1: 0.345006038, 2: 0.029864564},
 'Day6': {0: 0.155279503, 1: np.nan, 2: 0.044796846},
 'Day7': {0: 0.135869565, 1: np.nan, 2: 0.014932282},
 'Day8': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: 0.014932282}}
)

df.set_index('City', inplace=True)
df[['slope','intercept','r','p','se']] = df.apply(lambda x: linregress(range(1,len(x.dropna())+1), x.dropna().values), axis=1).apply(pd.Series)

print(df)
```

Comment: Congratulations for your fish. Centropomus?

Comment: @TonySampaio That's right!